# Separating Formbacking and Database backed Models . What is a valid approach

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

the last days i read many articles/comments/issues about everything related with the way the play examples suggest to structure a play app. The examples recommend to use the same Model/Class to back the Database AND Forms. But i have a problem with that. Form-Tampering and clutter code to handle updates(to just some fields of the model) from submitted forms... 
But when i search for solutions to those Problems, i often get to some github isues, where the play-core Team states, that people who are using the same Class for Formbacking and database, its their own fault.(https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2358) And their Comments imply that we should use separated Models for formbacking and Database.
Again, this is exactly contrary to what the examples say.

So "I" came up with a "solution"(after reading the great article https://github.com/ics-software-engineering/play-example-form)

So here is my approach.

Lets say i have a User Model. The user has some fields that should be editable by users(so they should go into the form) and some fields, that should not be editable by a simple form, like "isAdmin" or created/modified and so on.

So i created a normal play! User class with all the fields needed, along with the entity annotation etc. Just like a normal class, but without the validation.

Alongside i created a "UserFormModel". This is a POJO without any entity/database annotation/attribute, but with Validations (annotations and a validate() method).

Now my app uses this UserFormModel to represent Users in forms. It has a subset of Fields from the actual user.
Now even form-tampering cannot affect the non-public fields in my backend user class. The downside of this is, that i have to transfer the data from the UserFormModel to the actual user class every time i want to display/process a form for a user. With little fields, this is not a problem.

For this transfer i implemented a

```
public static User makeInstance(UserFormModel formData) {
    User user;
    if (formData.id != null) {
        user = findById(formData.id);
        user.setTestString(formData.testString);
    } else {
        user = new User();
    }
    return user;
}
```

in the User class which creates a user from the form model(either updates an existing on (id is present) or instantiates a new one)

Same goes for the UserFormModel

```
    public UserFormModel prefillFormModel(User user) {
    this.id = user.getId();
    this.testString = user.getTestString();
    this.jobs = user.getJobs();
    this.mails = user.getMails();
    return this;        
}
```

This prefills the Formbacking Model with the "public" fields from the actual user

What do you think about this approach?

As an improvement, if the UserFormModel has really just a subset of fields from the actual user, i'm playing with the idea of using reflection to get the data from one model to the other.
In the case i want to create a User object from the UserFormModel i could just iterate over all the public Fields in the UserFormModel, and call the appropriate setters of the actual user (if it follows the java beans convention, i can infer the name of the setter for a field from its name)
This would reduce the needed boilerplate code in every model to transfer the data back and forth.

Edit: After i sleep a night over this, i came to the question: HOW could anyone handle this design approach with nested form. Lets say i want to edit a user, and add some new Mail-Objects at the same time. With plain Play this is not a problem because my User has a Field List so it knows how to deal with it, including the @Valid annotation. But when i have a UserFormModel there is a problem, because this again just knows the Mail-Model which does not have annotations for validation(as i want to separate data domain objects from form models). What should i do here?! Declaring the List instead of List in the UserFormModel, and let the transformation back to real mails happen in the mail setter method of the actual User model? I thik this would work, but it adds an awefull lot of clutter....

Comment: I think i just decided to go for the "standard" approach. Use my data models also for formbacking. Just as in the examples. It's easier. Even though i maybe have to put some extra logic in the controllers for validation (not actual input validation, but stuff around it).

Answer (score 1):

It's a hard problem.  Ruby on Rails has a similar form-backed models approach.  But adjustments and customizations are easier in a dynamic language.

Your approach seems sound.  You can use reflection or code-generation to write the field-copying code.  Annotations are good for most validation, but Play also will look for a validate() method where you can put custom valdation code.

Comment: Any idea how i should handle the nested models? Like when i want to create a new Mail object inside the User-form?! Because when i say List<Mail> in the UserFormModel, with a @Valid, there is not validation in the mail data model, beacause I'm supposed to use the FOrm models. So this would circumvent my idea, to only use Form Models when doing stuff with user-input. Any suggestion(s)?